# PHP - HTML -JAVASCRIPT Copying values from form A into form B and using those from Form B as input for DB

Tags: javascript, forms, sql-insert

**This is what i have so far.**

1. To get the values from form A:

   $('.table tbody') .on('click','.btn',function(){
   var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
   var col1 = currow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
   var col2 = currow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
   var col3 = currow.find('td:eq(3)').text();
2. Checking the correct values

   alert(col1+col2+col3+col4);
3. setting these values to form 2

   ```
   document.getElementById("I2").innerHTML= col1;
   document.getElementById('I2').style.color = "white";
   document.getElementById("I3").innerHTML= col2;
   document.getElementById("I4").innerHTML= col3;
   ```

This all works fine, I have the values copied on Form B.  The issue appears in Form B, where I have an insert (into DB) button and this is not passing all the values taken from form A, they all appear as NULL values.
column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
It seems the browser does not pass the values.
Any hint on how to solve this problem will be very appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: you say you want to change the value of form elements but you are just changing the appearence of html tables showing in the document? if those elements (#I2,#I3,#I4) are input elements whose values will be submitted by the form, you should use the value property to set their value. Maybe you should include your html code because I'm afraid you are confused on the meaning of forms. By the way it's not clear reading your question

Comment: Hello, Thanks for answering and I am sorry for the confusion. I will try to clarify...

Comment: I have a HTML form A where I read fields from a DB, every row has a checkbox and depending on which checkbox is enabled I copy its values into another HTML form B for Input into another table... Your sentence hits it I think...  *you want to change the value of form elements but you are just changing the appearance of html tables showing in the document* ... I guess innerHTML is not correct here. Thanks

Comment: try with this: `document.getElementById("I2").value = col1;` (and so on for the other elements). Maybe that's the issue if I correctly got the conditions. Otherwise to be definitely clear you should share a complete and working example showing your problem and it will surely solved quickly by someone here.

Answer (score 0):

Using:
document.querySelector("#I2 input").value=col1;
Instead of:
document.getElementById("I2").innerHTML= col1;

Solved the Issue.
Thanks for your Input